# How to use TryParse method for car license plate inquiry at C#

Tags: c#, tryparse

I want the first two and the last 4 characters to be numbers and the rest to remain as strings. If these conditions are not met, the license plate number should be obtained again.I couldn't go further than the code below.

```
        static string PlakaAl(string plaka)
        {
            int sayi;

            while (true)
            {
                Console.Write(plaka);
                string giris = Console.ReadLine();
                if (giris.Length == 8 && int.TryParse(giris.Substring(0, 2), out sayi) == true && int.TryParse(giris.Substring(4, 4), out sayi == true)

                {
                    return plaka;
                }

                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Bu şekilde plaka girişi yapamazsınız. Tekrar deneyin.");

                }

            }
```

Comment: Hello you should use REGEX [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex?view=net-6.0)

Comment: `int.TryParse(giris.Substring(4, 4), out sayi == true` is missing the closing `)` of the tryparse. FYI you don't need to compare the bool result of tryparse with `true` to know that it is `true`

Answer (score 3):

This seems like it'd be a perfect opportunity to use a [regular expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference).

> A regular expression is a pattern that the regular expression engine attempts to match in input text. A pattern consists of one or more character literals, operators, or constructs.

You can use this to define a pattern for the expected format of these license plates. This pattern ought to work for you based on your question:

```
^\d{2}[A-Z]{2}\d{4}$
```

Here's an explanation of what each part of this pattern will match:

- `^` - the start of the string
- `\d{2}` - two digits
- `[A-Z]{2}` - two uppercase letters
- `\d{4}` - four digits
- `$` - the end of the string

**Note:** I wasn't clear what you meant by "the rest to remain as strings". If you want to allow more than alphabetic characters, you'd just need to update the `[A-Z]` [character group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-classes-in-regular-expressions#positive-character-group--) to include any other characters that are acceptable.

You can also see a visualization of this pattern [here](https://regexper.com/#%5E%5Cd%7B2%7D%5BA-Z%5D%7B2%7D%5Cd%7B4%7D%24) to help understand what it's doing.

You'd use it like this:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
...
var isValid = Regex.IsMatch(plaka, @"^\d{2}[A-Z]{2}\d{4}$");
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually RegEx is relatively slow (and objectively "easy" or "difficult" to read). You could also just test if the characters are digits (numbers) or letters:

```cs
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var good = "12bafd3456";
        var bad = "1mns356";
        
        Console.WriteLine(Test(good));
        Console.WriteLine(Test(bad));
    }
    
    public static bool Test(string str)
    {
        if (str.Length < 7) return false;
        var firstTwoIndex = 2;
        var lastFourIndex = str.Length - 4;
        for (var index = 0; index < str.Length; index++)
        {
            if (index < firstTwoIndex || index >= lastFourIndex)
            {
                if (!char.IsDigit(str[index])) return false;
            } else {
                if (!char.IsLetter(str[index])) return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

returns

```
True
False
```

According to Benchmarkdotnet, the performance difference is:

```
|   Method |     Mean |    Error |   StdDev | Allocated |
|--------- |---------:|---------:|---------:|----------:|
|    RegEx | 90.72 ns | 0.983 ns | 0.871 ns |         - |
| Function | 12.57 ns | 0.236 ns | 0.330 ns |         - |
```

edit: There's also a `Char.IsUpper` to test for an uppercase letter.

Comment: "Relatively slow." Not in the context of a data input form.

Comment: @JimMischel that might be, but stack overflow answers are public and reference by other developers in different contexts, where performance might matter.

Comment: and we expect developers to have some ability to understand the context in which the answer was given. It's unreasonable to expect an answer to a specific question to include disclaimers about the contexts in which the answer might not be appropriate. Your answer certainly is workable. But if you're going to say that "RegEx is relatively slow," then I'd expect you to back that up with timings to show that your solution is objectively faster.

Comment: @JimMischel ok, I tested it. My previous code was actually slower (and even required allocation). It seems RegEx in C# is way faster then I'm used from C++. However, when I use a simple loop over the characters, I'm faster again.

Comment: A lot of work went into Regex to make it performant. The Regex cache and compiled regular expressions are two of the features that I've used to greatly increase the speed of regular expression matches. It's good enough that if I see a problem that I can solve easily with a simple regular expression, I'll do it. And worry about looping or creating a custom parser only if the regex solution proves too slow.